# how to make the command line screen follow the curser?

Tags: linux, windows-10, console

I just installed a kali-linux on windows 10.
My problem is on the command prompt when I type `clear` to clear the screen everything get moved up of the screen, and left with black screen without any cursor, so that I have to press enter many times to make the cursor down again.

Comment: "installed a kali-linux on windows 10" — how?

Comment: using  windows 10 WSL

Comment: It seems you have a wrong number of lines & dimension of the characters set... (I mean the dimension of the characters * number of lines allowed > number of pixels of the current text screen resolution, so it scrolls up)... Please [edit] your post adding the procedure you used to install kali...

Comment: @Hastur thanks for the hint  , i just resized the windows  and it worked well

Comment: @karim You are welcome (I added the comment as answer). Feel you free to modify it adding particular that may result useful to others... and welcome on SuperUser. BTW really [edit] your question adding the procedure (or the link to the procedure) you followed... it may result useful for other people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a wrong number of lines & dimension of the characters set...
(I mean the dimension of the characters * number of lines allowed > number of pixels of the current text screen resolution, so it scrolls up)...

Try changing the dimension of the window...

---

**Bonus**
When you cannot fix problem like those you can use a *dirty patch*

```
alias C='clear; echo -e "\n\n\n\n"'
```

With alias you create your  command (`C`) that execute the usual `clear` and adds a number of newlines (`\n`) that depends on the lines you have to scroll down (in this case 4).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a WSL-ism.

Just because I can make bigger shoes “fit” by putting on 4 pears of socks doesn’t mean I should.

I would recommend a VM. Many of the pentest tools on kali expect to interface with the hardware in a specific way, and I wouldn’t trust WSL to do that degree.

VirtualBox is an excellent, well supported free option with many helpful tutorials out there. Put a Kali image on that.

https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2018/07/17/reasons-to-not-use-wsl.aspx?m=1

Comment: I have spotted a small grammar issue: Correct "4 pairs of socks" Incorrect "4 pears of socks"

Comment: "*pentest tools on kali expect to interface with the hardware in a specific way, and I wouldn’t trust WSL to do that degree*" I wouldn't trust a VM for this either...